# How to create a spring boot application that uses Kafka producer and consumer with out auto wiring

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka

Can anyone  help me how to create  a library  for Kafka messaging which is used by many other services

Answer (score 0):

The Spring Kafka documentation already covers this, but the same instructions apply if your weren't to use SpringBoot at all - create your own Properties and provide them to Kafka client  constructors...

Also, Boot wired properties can easily be re-used in other libraries.

Answer (score 0):

[Spring Kafka](https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka) already do it.

If you are using gradle, set the following the dependencies:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
implementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka'
```

If you want to create a project using Spring Kafka it is very easy with https://start.spring.io/

[image]